# Complete Bread board arduino

Tags: avr

I bought a ATmega328 microcontroller and burn the bootloader. Now I want to upload code directly from pc to the microcontroller on bread board. I have max232 ic for the communication but I recently knew that I need a serial port rather usb to connect max232 to pc. There are many usb to serial converter available on the market but can I make my own? One more thing is there any other way burn program from arduino ide to microcontroller via USB on bread board without having the arduino board. Or can I burn program to microcontroller on the bread board from arduino board without removing the on board ic.

Comment: If you don't have that hardware in place, you don't have an  "complete" Arduino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are many usb to serial converter available on the market but can I make my own?

Yes, but if you need to ask how then you're not ready to undertake the task.

> One more thing is there any other way burn program from arduino ide to microcontroller via usb on bread board without having the arduino board.

Yes. The IDE doesn't care how you connect to the MCU, only that it has the appropriate bootloader for the programming method.

> Or can I burn program to microcontroller on the bread board from arduino board without removing the on board ic.

[ArduinoISP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) will let you use an existing Arduino as an AVR ISP programmer. ISP does not require a bootloader, nor does it require a serial (UART) connection.

Comment: yea thank you. what is the issue of designing own usb to serial converter ;

Comment: Laying out a USB device needs knowledge and a bit of experience. It's not something for a novice.